# Debian Xfce, Proper GTK 3 Greybird Theme Integration with Chromium

Tags: debian, xfce, chrome, gtk3

I have Debian Stretch with Xfce desktop environment. I am using [Greybird](https://packages.debian.org/sid/greybird-gtk-theme) theme. I have used `gtk-theme-config` to add in my custom green color, hex `#324820`. I also replaced the default blue, `#398ee7`, with my custom green color with:

```
/usr/share/themes/Greybird$ sudo find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/#398ee7/#324820/g' {} \;
```

In any application when I right click, the highlighted item on the context menu is my green background with white text. However in Chromium it is a gray background `#cecece` with white text. I was able to change this in the file `/usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-3.0/gtk-contained.css` on line 23, `background-color: #cecece; }`. However, this also changes the tooltip background when I hover over things such as bookmarks. These have black text, `#3c3c3c`, leaving very poor readability on my dark green background. What changes can I make in this file, `gtk-contained.css`, that will integrate Chromium properly with my theme? I suppose I would like to do the equivalent of the following (from line 5 in `/usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`)  but in GTK 3:

```
gtk-color-scheme = "bg_color:#EEEEEE\nselected_bg_color:#324820\nbase_color:#fcfcfc" # Background, base.
```

In the above line I had changed the color for `selected_bg_color`.

In Chromium I am using the option "Use Classic theme" in Settings instead of "Use GTK+ theme".

Any ideas are welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by adding the `hover` pseudo class:

```
.background:hover {
  background-color: #324820; }
```

I added it in the following section which starts on line 21 of `/usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-3.0/gtk-contained.css`

```
.background {
  color: #3c3c3c;
  background-color: #cecece; }
  .background:hover {
    background-color: #324820; }
  .background:backdrop {
    color: #858585;
    background-color: #cecece;
    text-shadow: none;
    -gtk-icon-shadow: none; }
```

I have very few GTK 3 applications so this change may affect the styling of an application I don't use in a way I am not aware of.